# Проверить нажатие клавиши

Tags: python, клавиатура

Я столкнулся с проблемой при написании скрипта.
Я играю в игру, и там проблема в том, что я должен всегда держать клавишу <kbd>S</kbd>, и через некоторое время нажимать <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> не отпуская <kbd>S</kbd>. К этим действиям добавляется еще и кликание по мышке. И я не всегда нажимая Space до конца нажимаю <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Так вот. Я решил написать скрипт, который будет при нажатии клавиши Space сам нажимать <kbd>Shift</kbd>, на случай если я не дожму. Сделать я хочу это при помощи модуля клавиатуры `keyboard` в Python. Но вот если я впишу `keyboard.wait("space")`, то в моей ситуации это не поможет. Как я уже писал выше у меня всегда зажата клавиша <kbd>S</kbd>, а значит данный способ не сработает. Если вписать `keyboard.wait("space + s")`, то это сработает только в первый раз, а дальше не будет работать. Такой вариант я тоже пробовал.
Я решил попробовать так:

```py
import keyboard
from time import sleep
def is_pressed(e):
    if e.event_type == "down":
        if e.name == "space":
            keyboard.press("shift")
            sleep(0.25)
            keyboard.release("shift")
            
keyboard.hook(is_pressed)
```

Но проблема тут в другом. Это тоже не работает. Если я в свое условие вставлю принт, то при нажатии пробела и при зажатой клавише <kbd>S</kbd> `print` сработает, но вот сам <kbd>Shift</kbd> не нажмется. Пока что я остановился на этом варианте, но он не нажимает клавишу.
Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Функция sleep()блокирует выполнение программы из-за этого ошибка, попробуйте так

```
import asyncio
import keyboard

async def press_shift():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('space') and keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
            keyboard.press('shift')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
            keyboard.release('shift')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(press_shift())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```